# Removing an Event Listener is not working

Tags: javascript, removeeventlistener

A `mousemove` listener has been placed on a `<canvas>` tag. The listener works as expected. The problem is with attempting to remove the listener.

The program structure is that a check box is used to call the main function which has the following structure:

```
main_function(el) {  
    if (el.checked) {
        // ....
        sub_function();
        canvasEl.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveList);
        sub_function() {
            // ....
            mousemoveList() {
               // ....
            }
        }
     } else {
        canvasEl.removeEventListener('mousemove',mousemoveList);
     }
}
```

When the check box is clicked `main_function()` is called, the `el.checked` path is followed, the `sub_function()` is called - which has the `mousemoveList()` function - and lastly the listener is successfully added.

When the check box is unchecked the `else` path is followed where the listener is supposed to be removed. The problem is that the listener is not removed.

Keeping the above structure of the program how can the event listener issue be solved?

Comment: can you provide working fiddle?

Comment: Where is `mousemoveList` defined? I think this code will error as it is right now since the only `mousemoveList` here is out of scope.

Comment: Is the removeEventListener out of scope? it is simply down a different branch of the 'if' statement to the addEventListener and the addEventListener works!.

Comment: movemouseList is defined in the in the same branch as the addEventListener, that's why it works.  It needs to be defined outside of the if block if it is to be usable by both.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring nested functions like that? In general there is no reason to declare function definitions inside other functions, just make calls to them. Something like this might work better:

```
main_function(el) {  
    if (el.checked) {
        // ....
        sub_function();
        canvasEl.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveList);
     } else {
        canvasEl.removeEventListener('mousemove',mousemoveList);
     }
}

sub_function() {
    //...
}

mousemoveList() {
    // ....
}
```

and if you need to call your sub functions within higher functions, just call them

```
sub_function() {
    mouseMoveList();
}
```

Comment: Your input is appreciated but I need to keep the scoping as it is.

Comment: can you explain why?  or provide a link to more of the code?  the scoping is most likely the reason why your else statement doesn't have access to the mosemoveList function, they are not in the same scope.

Comment: Scoping allows variable sharing. The mousemoveList() function is using variables from the sub_function().

Comment: Ok while that may be true, your scoping is preventing the `removeEventListener` from accessing the function.  A better way to organize your code would be to add the values you need in the `mousemoveList` function as parameters to it and move it to a higher level of your scope.  And if it needs variables from sub_function, maybe the event listener should be for the sub function.  It is hard to say without knowing more about how your code actually functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complication things where It's not needed, I've made a simple codepen [example](https://codepen.io/prithweeDas/pen/xBPJLE) you can check, hope It will help

```js
const el = document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");

function mousemove() {
  console.log("mousemove");
}

el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) document.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
  else document.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Your response is appreciated. I tried the CodePen link and it did not load for me. With regard to the Stackoverflow code snippet you provided I'm still digesting it and seeing how it can help.

Comment: What loading are you talking about? even if the codepen doesn't open, I have the same code attached to the answer as a snipper, run that and you'll see that you'll get the mousemove only when the checkbox is checked.